# How to filter the options from a select list field according to a previous select list?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm trying to build a content type that has two selectlist fields.
My problem is that the first field should filter the second field options

For example:

First field options:
-Red (Selected)
-Blue
-Green

Second field options would be:
-Apple
-Strawberry
-Cherry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

You can set the controlling field (colors) to trigger the controlled field (fruit) when 'Red' is selected. You can change these settings by editing the Controlling field on the 'Manage Fields' page.

Comment: I believe the OP wants the options to change in the second select list when making a new selection in the first list, ie if "Green" was selected, filter the second list to "Grapes, Pear, Apple" etc

Comment: Yes Laxman. Using Conditional Fields allow me to show/hide a field, but do not filter the options for a second field

Comment: I solved it using Conditional fields, but if I had another "filter", it could not be solved this way